# Is it possible to add SELinux policy rule to restrict an application to a memory address range?

Tags: linux, security, selinux

Is it possible to add SELinux policy rule to restrict an application to a specific virtual or physical memory address range?  If so, which SELinux policy rule allows for a memory range to be specify?  Thanks.